# AWS Cloudwatch Canary - Nodejs puppeteer - searching for text in XML output

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, puppeteer, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-synthetics

I have built a cloudwatch canary using the gui, it has generated some code for me which I have adapted.
The idea is simply to query a web page which returns back some XML that looks like this:

```
<Description>
  <XYZ code="100" label="some text here" value="22"/>
  <ABC code="110" label="some text here" value="searchingforthistext"/>
</Description>
```

I want to search this URL for a specific string, if it matches we pass, if we can't find it then we fail. The string I am looking for is in the ABC-value section (and always will be)

My code looks like this so far:

```
const synthetics = require('Synthetics');
const log = require('SyntheticsLogger');
const syntheticsConfiguration = synthetics.getConfiguration();

const flowBuilderBlueprint = async function () {
    // INSERT URL here
    let url = "https://something.com/mypage";

    syntheticsConfiguration.setConfig({
        includeRequestHeaders: true, // Enable if headers should be displayed in HAR
        includeResponseHeaders: true, // Enable if headers should be displayed in HAR
        restrictedHeaders: [], // Value of these headers will be redacted from logs and reports
        restrictedUrlParameters: [] // Values of these url parameters will be redacted from logs and reports
    });
    let page = await synthetics.getPage();

    // Navigate to the initial url
    await synthetics.executeStep('navigateToUrl', async function (timeoutInMillis = 30000) {
        await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: ['load', 'networkidle0'], timeout: timeoutInMillis});
    });

    // Execute customer steps
    await synthetics.executeStep('verifyText', async function () {
      const exists = await page.waitForXPath("//ABC[@value='searchingforthistext']", { timeout: 5000 } );
      if (exists) {
        console.log('text found')
      } else {
        console.log('text not found')
      }
    });
};

exports.handler = async () => {
    return await flowBuilderBlueprint();
};
```

And it basically works, if the string is there the canary passes, if not it fails but it fails with a timeout error.

```
TimeoutError: Waiting for selector `.//ABC[@value='searchingforthistext']` failed: Waiting failed: 5000ms exceeded Stack: TimeoutError: Waiting for selector `.//ABC[@value='searchingforthistext']` failed: Waiting failed: 5000ms exceeded at Timeout.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/WaitTask.js:65:32) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

As you can see I've tried adding a check with some logging output but it hasn't made any difference. How can I make the output from this check more meaningful?